# Is there a way to use my array of type Music, in another scope?

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to print/dump and array of type Music outside of a function it's created in. I can successfully dump the musicItems array inside of the getMusicData function but when I set the musicItems array outside of the scope, it won't print anything. What am I doing wrong with the scope here? I have a feeling it's super simple but I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

edit: It's giving me "0 elements" in the console when I attempt to dump the musicItems array in the ViewController class. Well, the function is in the same class as well so I guess I don't know what to call the first array. The parent array?

```
struct MusicResults: Decodable {
    let results: [Music]?
}

struct Music: Decodable {
    let trackName: String?
    let collectionName: String?
    let artworkUrl30: String?

    }


class ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate  {

    var musicItems: [Music] = []

    @IBAction func musicButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        getMusicData()
        dump(musicItems)

    }
```

Here is the function.

```
func getMusicData() {
        var musicItems: [Music] = []
        guard let searchTerm = searchString else {return}
        let newString = searchTerm.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: .literal, range: nil)
        let jsonUrlString = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?media=music&term=\(newString)"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else { return }


            do {


                let music = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicResults.self, from: data)
                for results in music.results! {
//                    print(results.trackName!)
                    musicItems.append(results)
                }
                //dump(musicItems)
                self.musicItems = musicItems
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self.tableView.reloadData()
//                }



            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }



            }.resume()


    }
```

Fixed Code

```
@IBAction func musicButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    getMusicData {
        music in
        dump(music)
    }
```

function:

```
 func getMusicData(completionHandler: @escaping (_ music: [Music]) -> ()) {

...


 let music = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicResults.self, from: data)
                for results in music.results! {
                    musicItems.append(results)
                }
                completionHandler(musicItems)

...
```

Comment: You're declaring `musicItems` in two places, one is a locally scoped variable in your `getMusicData` function, the other is a member variable of your `ViewController` class.  Even if `getMusicData` is a member function of `ViewController`, the locally scoped `musicData` overrides any member variable.  See [this answer](/a/24251066/2487517) and [this one](/a/26507349/2487517) that discuss how to pass an array by reference as a parameter

Comment: Your `self.musicItems` is available only after `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` has completed. You call `dump(musicItems)` directly after the call of `getMusicData()`. The dataTask is not yet completed at that time. Search with "swift get result asynchronous" and you will find many, many, so many articles. Simply move `dump(musicItems)` inside the completionHandler.

Comment: Thanks @OOPer ! You guys helped immensely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'getMusicData' function is asynchronous which means that when it executes, it queues data task in a background queue and proceeds the execution and since there are no more institutions it simply returns control to its calling site - 'musicButton()' action, which in its turn executes the next instruction - prints the 'musicItems' array which might (and most likely, is) still not populated as the network call haven’t yet completed. One of the options that you have here is to pass a completion block to your 'getMusicData' function, that runs it after data task gets the results.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [Property Observers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

```
var musicItems: [Music] = [] {
    didSet {
        dump(self.musicItems)
/// This is where I would do the...
//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                self.tableView.reloadData()
//            }
    }
}
```

and then

```
func getMusicData() {
    guard let searchTerm = searchString else { print("no search"); return }
    let newString = searchTerm.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: .literal, range: nil)
    let jsonUrlString = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?media=music&term=\(newString)"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { print("url error"); return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { print(err ?? "unknown"); return }
        do {
            let music = try JSONDecoder().decode(MusicResults.self, from: data)
            if let results = music.results {
                self.musicItems.append(contentsOf: results)
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Wow this is great. Thank you!